# How to retrieve a function or method's argument / parameter list from outside the function in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, introspection

In another class elsewhere in the code, I want to access the parameters (and their types) of `Foo.bar`. 
The result would contain `[ "a",  Number ]` and `[ "b", String ]` in one form or another.

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    public function bar(a:Number, b:String):void
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS3 has a method called [`describeType`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29)

If you call `describeType(Foo)` on the above example, you'll get:

```
<type name="Foo" base="Class" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="true">
  <extendsClass type="Class"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readonly" type="*" declaredBy="Class"/>
  <factory type="Foo">
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <method name="bar" declaredBy="Foo" returnType="void">
      <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
      <parameter index="2" type="String" optional="false"/>
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="51"/>
      </metadata>
    </method>
    <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
      <arg key="pos" value="23"/>
    </metadata>
  </factory>
</type>
```

Now, you can use AS3's `XML` class and e4x to find the definition of the method with the name `bar` and grab the `parameter` elements.